# What is the difference between using "is" or "get" in java when calling it with HTL

Tags: java, aem, sightly

In AEM, when we call some method or function to be used in our HTL front end code, something like this.

```java
public boolean isAboolean() {
    return "test";
}
```

and for the HTML, template language HTL

```html
<sly data-sly-test.boolean="${property.Aboolean}" />
```

The same thing happens with "get", do we need to add it in the HTL code or can we just write the method name without "is" or "get"?

Do we have to do it this way, or will it work this way ?

```html
<sly data-sly-test.boolean="${property.isAboolean}" />
```

Comment: On this [page](https://dzone.com/articles/java-getter-and-setter-basics-common-mistakes-and) have a look at "Naming Convention for Getter and Setter"

Comment: Thanks, my question is more regarding the template language HTL and if calling "{property.isAboolean}" will work oppose to "{property.Aboolean}"

Comment: You can use `property.isAboolean()` (with the parentheses, an actual method call) or `property.aboolean` (specifying a property name that will get converted into the method call).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HTL specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#112-expressions) is a bit generic and says that you can access **members** like this: `${myObject.key}`. The default implementation (Sling/AEM) follows the JavaBeans naming convention and will attempt to call either `getKey()` or `isKey()`. It will also attempt to call `key()` or output a field named `key` in case of POJOs. A bit more information is available in the [AEM docs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/expression-language.html?lang=en) (Property Access section).

For your example, you need to adjust the case of the member in the HTL expression: `${property.aboolean}` and `${property.isAboolean}` should both result in calling `isAboolean()` method.

Since it’s not allowed to call methods with parameters, parentheses are not used.